# Vue Switch showing always off

Tags: vue.js

When I click on the edit button on my page edit form is opened and it contains some switches. I am getting value '1' from DB but in the edit form switch is always off. How can I resolve this?

### edit.vue

```
<d-field-group class="field-group field-row" label-for = "Zip_Need" label="Does it need zip/postal code?" label-class="col-4">
    <d-switch id="Zip_Need" name="Zip_Need" v-model="form.Zip_Need" ></d-switch>
</d-field-group>
```

### Script

```
editCountry(id){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'); 
              axios.get(baseUrl+'/country/edit/'+id)
              .then((response) => {

                    this.form = response.data[0].form;
                     setTimeout(() => {
                         this.subComponentLoading = true;
                    }, 500);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show relevant bits of code so we can check where the problem may be?

Comment: @T.Dirks I have added Some code

Comment: What is `d-switch`?

Comment: @T.Dirks How can I set value to switch ?

Comment: @Kevin Can you show us your `d-switch` component code?

Comment: I am getting value as string but i need like a boolean

Comment: Would be more helpful if the code for `d-field-group`, & `d-switch` in particular, was provided